# Prove that $(\mathfrak{a} : \sum_i \mathfrak{b}_i ) = \bigcap_i (\mathfrak{a} : {\mathfrak{b}_i} ) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

[1] Is the following result true?

$$\bigcap_i (\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i ) = \left(\mathfrak{a} : \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right) $$

[2] Prove that $\left(\mathfrak{a} : \sum_i \mathfrak{b}_i\right) = \bigcap_i \left(\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i \right) $ where $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}_i$'s are ideals and $(\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i ) $ denotes the ideal quotient ring.

Recall that ideal quotient ring $(\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b} ) = \{x \in A : x \mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{a} \} $.

My attempt:

[1]Proof: Let
\begin{align*}
& x \in \bigcap_i (\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i ) \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow x \in (\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i ) \;  \forall i \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow x \mathfrak{b}_i \subset \mathfrak{a} \;  \forall i \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow \; \bigcap_i  (x \mathfrak{b}_i)  \subset \mathfrak{a} \\[2pt] 
& \Rightarrow \; x \left( \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right)  \subset \mathfrak{a} \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow \; x \in \left(\mathfrak{a} : \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right)
\end{align*}

Conversely if

\begin{align*}
& x \in \left(\mathfrak{a} : \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right) \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow x \left( \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right) \subset \mathfrak{a} \\[2pt]
&  \Rightarrow x ( \mathfrak{b}_i ) \subset  \mathfrak{a} \; \forall i \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow x \subset  (\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i ) \;  \forall i \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow x \subset  \bigcap_i (\mathfrak{a} : \mathfrak{b}_i ) \\[2pt]
\end{align*}

No idea of how to proceed for [2].

Comment: In general, the converse of [1] is wrong, and you made a mistake in the second implication.

Comment: Instead, [2] is correct. You can proceed as you did, and recall that a sum of ideals contains any of them.

Answer (score 1):

I see that I have made a mistake in the following step.

\begin{align*}
& x \in \left(\mathfrak{a} : \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right) \\[2pt]
& \Rightarrow x \left( \bigcap_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right) \subset  \mathfrak{a} \nRightarrow x ( \mathfrak{b}_i ) \subset  \mathfrak{a} \; \forall i
\end{align*}

While the solution to problem (2) is:

\begin{align*}
x \left(\sum_i \mathfrak{b}_i \right) & \subset \mathfrak{a} \\
 \Rightarrow x \mathfrak{b}_i &\subset \mathfrak{a}  \quad \forall i \\
 \Rightarrow x &\in (\mathfrak{a}  : \mathfrak{b}_i)   \quad \forall i \\
 \Rightarrow x &\in \bigcap_ i (\mathfrak{a}  : \mathfrak{b}_i)
\end{align*}

In step (2), we have used the fact that if sum of ideals contains any of them as suggested by @user26857 .